# LNK 1194 building node-ofe on windows7 with msbuild 14.0 (msvc 2015), node 6.5.0

Tags: node.js, windows-7, out-of-memory, node-gyp

I get this when I say

```
npm install ofe

LINK : fatal error LNK1194: cannot delay-load 'node.exe' due to import of data symbol '"__declspec(dllimport) const v8::OutputStream::`vftable'" (__imp_??_7OutputStream@v8@@6B@)'; link without /DE
LAYLOAD:node.exe [C:\tmp\ofe\node_modules\ofe\build\ofe.vcxproj]
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?